# Pass information from one layer to another

Tags: c#, mvvm

Abstract view: I want to pass information from one layer to another (*note: when there's a better title for this thread let me know*).

I have a ViewModel which communications with my Views and my Service layer.
And I have a Service layer communication with my persistence layer.

Let's assume I have the following classes:

```
public class EmployeeViewModel()
{
    // The following properties are binded to my View (bidirectional communication)
    public Firstname ...
    public Lastname ...
    public Email ...

    public void PerformingSearch()
    {
        ...
        EmployeeService.Search(...);
        ...
    }
}

public class EmployeeService()
{
    public List<Employee> Search(...)
    {
        // Searching in db
    }
}
```

What is best practice to hand over the data from my ViewModel to my Service layer (e. g. for performing a search)?

I see a few options (ViewModel perspective):

1. EmployeeService.Search(Firstname, Lastname, Email);
2. EmployeeService.Search(employeeSearchModel); // In this case I would need another model. How should the model be instantiated?
3. EmployeeService.Search(this); // Convertion has to be done somewhere

Is there any design pattern for this problem? How is it called? What option is best? Did I miss anything?

Comment: Does your viewmodel contain the needed business logic for the use case(s)? I assume that you have no other (domain/persistence) models in place for the sake of keeping your architecture simple... ? Asking this because currently we don't have detailed overview about your architecture and to me it's kinda hard to recommend you a concise answer.

Comment: ViewModel should contain no business logic. The business logic is placed inside the service layer. Between service layer and database is my data access layer. So far I use models to transform data from/to database primarily.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Describing your problem space

Your particular example tells me that your current architecture contains a service layer that sort of acts as a proxy to your data access layer. Without more in-depth knowledge of your architecture I would suggest a possible solution to [keep it simple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) as much as your environment allows.

Now let's try to pick a *strategy* to get a possible solution model. 
Your user story sounds like: *"a user submits information to obtain a list of employees"*.

Your current use-case simplified:

1. UI: submits some information that you need to serve;
2. VM: receives the search terms and passes it next to the service layer;
3. SL: sends the received data to Data Access Layer (and maybe updates the response values to VM properties);
4. DAL: looks up information in persistence store and returns the obtained values.

---

A refactored use-case example:

1. VM: invokes a query with the needed values encapsulated and set the properties to display in the UI.

Looks easier right?

#### Enter: [Command Query Separation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command%E2%80%93query_separation)

In short CQS:

> States that every method should either be a command that performs
>   an action, or a query that returns data to the caller, but not both.

In your particular case we need to focus on [queries](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/CommandQuerySeparation.html), where:

> **Queries:** Return a result and do not change the observable state of the system (are free of side effects).

**But how does this help you?** Let's see.
A very good and detailed explanation of CQS query-side can be read fully at the "[Meanwhile... on the query side of my architecture](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=92)" blog post from [Steven](https://stackoverflow.com/users/264697/steven).

#### Query concept applied to your problem

Defining an interface for the query object

```
public interface IQuery<TResult> {}
```

The query handler definition:

```
public interface IQueryHandler<TQuery, TResult> where TQuery : IQuery<TResult>
{
    TResult Handle(TQuery query);
}
```

Now here is an implementation of your *"search"* query object. This is effectively the answer for your *"how to pass information"* question :

```
public class FindEmployeeBySearchTextQuery : IQuery<Employee>
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

And last a query handler that you will pass in your query object:

```
public class FindEmployeeBySearchTextQueryHandler
    : IQueryHandler<FindEmployeeBySearchTextQuery, List<Employee>>
{
    private readonly IDbContext db;

    public FindEmployeeBySearchTextQueryHandler(IDbContext db)
    {
        this.db = db;
    }

    public List<Employee> Handle(FindEmployeeBySearchTextQuery query)
    {
        return (
            from employee in this.db.employees
            where employee.FirstName.Contains(query.FirstName) ||
                  employee.LastName.Contains(query.LastName) ||
                  employee.Email == query.Email
            select employee )
            .ToList();
    }
}
```

Note: this `Handle()` example implementation uses Entity Frameworks' `IDbContext`, you have got to rework/modify this according to your needs (ADO.NET, NHibernate, etc.).

And finally in your view model:

```
public class EmployeeViewModel()
{
    private readonly IQueryHandler _queryHandler;
    public EmployeeViewModel(IQueryHandler queryHandler) 
    {
        _queryHandler = queryHandler;
    }

    public void PerformingSearch()
    {
        var query = new FindEmployeeBySearchTextQuery
        {
            FirstName = "John", 
            LastName = "Doe",
            Email = "stack@has.been.over.flowed.com"
        };

        List<Employee> employees = _queryHandler.Handle(query);

        // .. Do further processing of the obtained data
    }
}
```

This example assumes that you are using Dependency Injection.
You get IQueryHandler implementation injected into your view models constructor and later work with the received implementation.

Using this approach your code becomes cleaner, more use-case driven and will have better isolation of responsibilities which you can easily test and decorate with further cross-cutting concerns.