# Repository Pattern with Fluent Nhibernate

Tags: fluent-nhibernate, repository-pattern

Hello everyone I've successfully implemented the repository pattern with fluentNHibernate but i have one concern abount the ***ExposeConfiguration*** when I removed it all the methods works fine but when i adds it ,it resets the tables in the database. so i need you to take a look and give me any notes about the implementation so here is my unit of work class

```
 public class UnitOfWork 
{

    public static ISession  NhibernateHelper()
    {
        ISessionFactory _sessionFactory = Fluently.Configure()
            .Database(MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2012.ConnectionString(@"Data Source=WAAIL-PC\COMPUTERENGINEER;Initial Catalog=TSQL2012;User ID=sa;Password=12345678Ce").ShowSql())
            .Mappings(x => x.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<UsersMap>())
           //.ExposeConfiguration(cfg => new SchemaExport(cfg).Create(false, true)) //when i removed this line it doesn't
          //remove the elements from the db
            .BuildSessionFactory();

       return _sessionFactory.OpenSession();

    }}
```

and here is my repository pattern :

```
public class Repository<T> :IRepository<T> where T :BaseEntity
{

    public Repository(/*IUnitOfWork unitOfWork*/)
    {
        //_unitOfWork = (UnitOfWork)unitOfWork;
    }

    public List<T> GetAll()
    {
        using (ISession Session = UnitOfWork.NhibernateHelper())
        {
            return Session.Query<T>().ToList();
        }
    }

    public T GetById(int id)
    {
        using (ISession Session = UnitOfWork.NhibernateHelper())
        {
            return Session.Get<T>(id);
        }
    }

    public T Insert(T entity)
    {
        try
        {
            using (ISession Session = UnitOfWork.NhibernateHelper())
            {
                using (ITransaction Transaction = Session.BeginTransaction())
                {
                    Session.Save(entity);
                    Transaction.Commit();
                }
            }
            return entity;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }
    }

    public void Update(T entity)
    {
        using (ISession Session = UnitOfWork.NhibernateHelper())
        {
            using (ITransaction Transaction = Session.BeginTransaction())
            {
                Session.Update(entity);
                Transaction.Commit();
            }
        }
    }

    public void Delete(int id)
    {
        using (ISession Session = UnitOfWork.NhibernateHelper())
        {
            using (ITransaction Transaction = Session.BeginTransaction())
            {
                Session.Delete(Session.Load<T>(id));
                Transaction.Commit();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

here is my usersService

```
public class UsersService : IUsersService
{
    private readonly IRepository<Users> _Repository;

    #region Constructor
    public UsersService(IRepository<Users> Repository)
    {
        _Repository = Repository;
    }
    #endregion

    #region Service Implementation

    public List<Users> GetListAll()
    {
        return _Repository.GetAll().ToList();
    }

    public Users GetById(int Id)
    {
        return _Repository.GetById(Id);
    }

    public Users Insert(Users user)
    {
        return _Repository.Insert(user);
    }

    public void Update(Users user)
    {
        _Repository.Update(user);
    }
    public void Delete(int Id)
    {
        _Repository.Delete(Id);
    }

    //public int execute()
    //{
    //    return _Repository.execute();
    //}


}
```

so what i need to know is why the Expose_configuration method causes the tables to reset... and secondly ,Am i moving in the right way in this implementation or not.
if you guys have any update of improvements please tell me ..
best regards.

Answer (score 3):

#### The evil lies in details

You wrote:

> ... ExposeConfiguration when I removed it all the methods works fine but when i add it, it resets the tables in the database.

And that's pretty much normal way of operations, since if we look up NHiberate's `SchemaExport` classes [`Create`](https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/blob/master/src/NHibernate/Tool/hbm2ddl/SchemaExport.cs#L103) method signature, it reads:

```
public void Create(Action<string> scriptAction, bool execute)
```

It's documentation states that `Create()`:

> Run the schema creation script

And about it parameters:

> **scriptAction** - an action that will be called for each line of the generated ddl.
>
> **execute** - if the ddl should be executed against the Database.

And you call it as:

```
.ExposeConfiguration(cfg => new SchemaExport(cfg).Create(false, true))
```

Your problem lies in that you pass `true` to the `execute` parameter, which will -as stated in documentation- execute the schema creation script, which might include drop and rerecration of existing database objects.

#### Why create demons?

About your second idea, I really see no benefit of adding another layer of indirection to your code, and that's where you summon unneeded demons.

The NHibernate ORM itself *is* an abstraction itself, why add one more generic one around it? Your `Repository<T>` just simply calls the already implemented generic NHibernate methods... sort of acting as [Proxy](http://www.dofactory.com/net/proxy-design-pattern) to hide NHibernate, if that's intentional please pardon me, but it looks like it's not.

On a final note: your `UsersService` class first violates the [Single responsibility principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) and makes your life *harder* by maintaining and testing it. Second, this class is also not much more than a proxy to call the repository to return values from.

Let me illustrate the problem:

1. Client calls `UsersService.GetById(Id)`
2. Service calls `_Repository.GetById(Id)`
3. Your generic abstraction Repository calls NHibernates `Session.Get<T>(id)`

Do you see the problem?

How easier it would be to say use a pattern that might help you in this case, that is the [Command Query Separation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command%E2%80%93query_separation).

Where your commands are responsible for writes, and queries about reads and both suits your use-cases.

You can read about my answers earlier about [queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39406126/pass-information-from-one-layer-to-another/39412106#39412106) and [commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36428850/cqrs-pattern-interfaces/36435439#36435439).

Comment: then you're saying as long as we implementing the fluentNHibernate then the repository pattern isn't necessary?right?

Comment: Right, if nothing enforces you to have that extra layer of abstraction, exactly that, yes!